# Why is my url is going to an empty landing page when I test it in their browser?

Tags: html, css, url

This is my url-
https://ad.atdmt.com/i/img;p=11002203374881;idfa=;idfa_lat=;aaid=;aaid_lat=;cache=

The code looks like-

```
<img height="1" src="https://ad.atdmt.com/i/img;p=11002203374881;idfa=;idfa_lat=;aaid=;aaid_lat=;cache="
     style="display: none" width="1"> </img>
```

Please suggest how I can correct my code and url. Thanks!

Comment: `display: none;` removes elements from the document.

Comment: It's a 1x1 image with `display: none`. What do you _expect_ to happen?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

size it biger 
and take the display:none off

Comment: Hi @DanyCode, can 1x1 and display:none lead to a an empty landing page when they test it in their browser? Thanks.

Comment: display: none means it will not show it. even if it will be 100px on 100px you will see nothing cause it is display:none that is what display:none does

Comment: @DanyCode- Thank you.